# R- Use a string as an expression

Tags: r, concatenation

I'll preface this by saying I know this is a slightly odd question to ask but I don't know how else to phrase it.

I have the following lines in a particular R script:

```
hist(sce$total_counts/1e6, xlab="Library sizes (millions)", main="", 
 breaks=20, col="grey80", ylab="Number of cells");
```

For this bit:

```
sce$total_counts/1e6
```

The `1e6` part should be an user input and I am trying to set it up so that the the first part and the user part get "concatenated" and then evaluated. Problem is using paste and other stuff returns strings and I don't want strings. I want to be able to swap out the "/1e6" part with "/1e3" for example and not change anything else about that line of code and still have it work. I tried to do the following:

```
object <- paste("sce$total_counts", args[1], sep="")
ob <- parse(text=object) # expression(sce$total_counts/1e6)
hist(ob, xlab="Library sizes (millions)", main="", 
 breaks=20, col="grey80", ylab="Number of cells");
```

But it returned this error:

```
Error in hist.default(ob, xlab = "Library sizes (millions)", main = "",  : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

I don't know how else to word it other than to say: How do you alias one part of the code as something else? I want `ob` with the user input of "/1e6" to mean the same as `sce$total_counts/1e6`

Comment: There's no need for all this pasting etc. Just do `x <- 1:100; val <- 1e6; hist(x/val)` - you can change `val` to whatever denominator you want.

Comment: Try `eval(parse(text=object))`

Comment: @DominicComtois - To quote `fortunes::fortune(106)` "*If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.*"

Comment: @thelatemail I know... It's a quick & dirty solution, but sometimes... anyway... maybe we'd need to know more about the way the OP gets the user input. A simple `as.numeric(user_input)` could work in some cases...

Comment: @DominicComtois You're right. as.numeric just ended up fixing everything. I was being dumb. I saw the 'e' and automatically assumed it was a string instead of a number!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the idea is that you want to perform aribitrary transformations on the first argument of `hist` before performing the histogram then pass a function that does the transformation

```
myhist <- function(f, ...) {
  f <- match.fun(f)
  x <- 1:20
  hist(f(x, ...))
}

# test runs
myhist("/", 1e6)
myhist(function(x) x / 1e3)
f <- function(x) x / 100; myhist(f)
myhist(sqrt)
```

It would also be possible to pass a function in formula form like this.  See `?fn`:

```
library(gsubfn)
fn$myhist(~ x / 1e6)
fn$myhist(~ sqrt(x))
```

Comment: There might be an issue with security here. What if the user passes in some evil function?

Comment: Agreed, and if the user is the programmer at the CLI that's fine, but it might not be if the user is e.g. someone on the other end of a Shiny web application.

Comment: Incidentally an alternative way to shorten the function definitions would be with `dplyr`/`magrittr`: for example, `myhist(. %>% {./3})` or `myhist( . %>% sqrt %>% log)`.

Comment: Sorry but I think the UI comment is not relevant.  It's about the question which seems to ask for the ability to make arbitrary transformations and therefore not specifically about this answer but rather pertains to any answer.  If you really insist on making such points it would be better to make them as comments to the question.

Comment: The magrittr idea is intersting.  Note that the magrittr function definition requires that you use dot but `fn$` allows any variable name.  We used `x` in the examples here but any name could have been used. It scans the formula for free variables and assumes they are the arguments in the order encountered.  Alternately if one prefers to be explicit one can specify the arguments as a sum on the LHS of the formula so `x ~ sqrt(x)` is the same as `~ sqrt(x)`.